# Polymorphic associations with images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, carrierwave, polymorphic-associations

sorry in advance for my bad english. I have generated with rails two models, an Article model and a Picture model. In the Picture model I have used CarrierWave to upload images. Now my problem is how to save images in the database table when I complete the article form. When I upload the images and then press submit, the form saves all the data, except the images. I suppose that I have a problem with the Article controller.
I would save images for each article and I do it with a form where I upload multiple images. The uploading comes abuot CarrierWave. But when I submit the form, I obtain the show view with all the params of the article (title, description, ..) except the images. I used polymorphic associations because I need to use the Picture model also for other models.
The article form is:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @article], html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <h4><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h4>

      <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :article_category_id, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.collection_select :article_category_id, ArticleCategory.all, :id, :name, {},  {class: "form-control"} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tag (separati dalla virgola)", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :tag_list, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :pictures, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.file_field :pictures, multiple: true %>
      <p>larghezza: 800px - altezza: 800px<br />DPI 72<br />peso inferiore a 50kb<br />tipo file jpg o png (scarica esempio da <%= link_to "qui", "/res/test.jpg", :target => "_blank" %>)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.date_select :date, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :status, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(Article.statuses.collect{|item, val| [item.humanize, item]}, selected: @article.status), class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The article controller is:

```
class Admin::ArticlesController < Admin::AdminController

  include Sortable

  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @articles = Article.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @article], notice: 'Articolo creato con successo.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @article], notice: 'Articolo aggiornato con successo.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_articles_url, notice: 'Articolo eliminato con successo.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:article_category_id, :title, :description, :date, :tag_list, :status, :pictures_attributes => [:id, :picturable_type, :picturable_id, :image => []])
    end

end
```

The article model is:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  acts_as_list
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags

  belongs_to :article_category
  has_many :comments
  has_many :pictures, as: :picturable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures

  enum status: {bozza: 0, pubblicato: 1}

  default_scope  {order("position ASC")}

  def final_image_url
    if self.image.present?
      return self.image_url
    else
      return "/res/no-image.png"
    end
  end
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: articles
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  article_category_id :integer
#  title               :string(255)
#  description         :text(65535)
#  date                :date
#  created_at          :datetime         not null
#  updated_at          :datetime         not null
#  position            :integer
#  status              :integer
#
```

and the picture model is:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :picturable, polymorphic: true

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: pictures
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  image               :string(255)
#  picturable_type     :string(255)
#  picturable_id       :integer
#  created_at          :datetime         not null
#  updated_at          :datetime         not null
#
```

where the uploader, is set as:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you paste your parameters here which are showing in logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your form code with below :-

```
.................
................
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tag (separati dalla virgola)", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :tag_list, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures, f.object.pictures.build do |picture| %>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= picture.file_field :image, class: "form-control"%>
      <p>larghezza: 800px - altezza: 800px<br />DPI 72<br />peso inferiore a 50kb<br />tipo file jpg o png (scarica esempio da <%= link_to "qui", "/res/test.jpg", :target => "_blank" %>)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.date_select :date, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
..............
..............
```

And change your controller permit method with below code :-

```
def article_params
   params.require(:article).permit(:article_category_id, :title, :description, :date, :tag_list, :status, :pictures_attributes => [:id, :image])
end
```

then try again to submit your form... :)